# C# HTTP Request using Socket returning 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: c#, sockets, http, http-get

My application has to send HTTP Requests to an external website using socket (this is the requirement). I am creating a socket at port 80.

Below is the code

```
class Program  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[4]; // this is resolving
        IPEndPoint RHost = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 80);

        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.Connect(RHost);

        string HTTPRequestHeaders_String = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: google.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: text/html\r\nUser-Agent: ConnectionTest\r\n\r\n";

        Console.WriteLine(HTTPRequestHeaders_String);

        byte[] HTTPRequestHeaders = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HTTPRequestHeaders_String);
        socket.Send(HTTPRequestHeaders, SocketFlags.None);

        String Response = "";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)socket.ReceiveBufferSize];

        int bytes;
        do {
            bytes = socket.Receive(buffer);
            Response += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
            Console.WriteLine(Response);
        } while (bytes >= 0);
    }
}
```

**So For the above Request**

GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: google.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html
User-Agent: ConnectionTest

**Response is**

HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Date: Mon, 06 Sep 2021 18:45:14 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 326

Service Unavailable

### Service Unavailable

---

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

I have the following process running on my machine

```
PS C:\> Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen,Established -LocalPort 80 | select LocalPort, State, OwningProcess

LocalPort  State OwningProcess
---------  ----- -------------
       80 Listen             4

PS>Get-Process -Id 4
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                                                                    
   8216       0      200         96  27,597.17      4   0 System
```

Can you help me identify what is wrong with my code?

Comment: could be the host header, what ipaddress are you attempting to connect to?

Comment: also many services also require https

Comment: "ipAddress" is the IP address of my local machine (laptop).
I tried HTTPS with port 443, it didn't work

Comment: Your code has worked just fine. You need to check your server to see what went wrong and why it responded with a 503.   You should look at using the WebRequest class.

Comment: I have following process running on my machine on port 80

PS C:\> Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen,Established -LocalPort 80 | select LocalPort, State, OwningProcess

LocalPort  State OwningProcess
---------  ----- -------------
       80 Listen             4

PS>Get-Process -Id 4
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                                                                    
   8216       0      200         96  27,597.17      4   0 System

Comment: The 503 is coming back from your server that is listening on Port 80.  This is the actual response that that server is sending - this is not an internal Windows error.  Your code connects to that server, your code sends it's headers - your code has worked correctly.  That server then receives your headers and sends back "503 ..." your server that is listening on port 80 is actually putting that text on the wire and sending it over the  TCP Socket connection.  This is not some internal Windows error message.